# Prevent scroll to the top when getJSON is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, preventdefault

Im very confused right now.

Here is my code:

```
    $("#combinations").on("change", "input", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
   console.log(e)
        var $button, $row, $group, $form, $barcodeValidation, url, barcodeVal;
        $button = $(this);
        $row = $button.closest(".input-group");
        $group = $row.closest(".form-group");
        $form = $group.closest("form");
        $barcodeValidation = $row.find("#barcode-validation");
        barcodeVal = $row.find("input").val();
        url = "/Product/CheckBarcode";
        var productNumber = $form.find("#Product_Number").val();

        $.getJSON(url, {
            barcode: barcodeVal,
            productNumber: productNumber
        }).done(function (result) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }).fail(function (result) {
        });

    });
```

so when some combinations input changes i want to make a request to the server and check some. But for some reason every time this request happends page keep scrolling to top. If i outcomment Ajax request part, everything is fine.

How do i prevent such behavior?

**Edit**

Markup :

```
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">

                            <div class="combinations">
                                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Combinations)
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Editor contains some input fields.

Comment: can you hare working issue in fidder ?

Comment: can you share working issue in fidder or live url to check ? because your code seem no issue.

Comment: what is "#combinations" a,button,div?

Comment: in shown code it doesn't seem smth, that can affect the page scroll; But waht can be point for further investigation - 'change' event fires on inputs when they loose focus, so maybe you should check what u do after you type

Comment: I was not able to duplicate the behavior. The question is difficult to answer with the information provided. Please explain "page keep scrolling to top". Do you mean the scroll value has change, the hash value has changed, or the page has refreshed? What do you see in the network tab of the dev console? What is the html structure of the page?

Comment: @Robert  Updated markup, network just says that getJson is called to CheckBarcode method, and afterwards page just jumps/scrolls to the top

Comment: The sinner was ajaxStart event on layout page

Answer (score 0):

The e.preventDefault(); before calling the $.getJSON() should do the trick.